# How to vectorise looping through pandas groupby dataframes whilst appyling conditionals

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements, vectorization

I am trying to organise some data into groups based on the contents of certain columns. The current code I have is dependent on loops and I would like to vectorise instead to improve performance. I know this is the way forwards with pandas and whilst I can vectorise some problems I am really struggling with this one.

What I need to do is group the data by the ClientNumber and link the genuine and incomplete rows so that for each Clientnumber all the genuine rows have a different process ID and the incomplete rows are given the same process ID as the nearest genuine row which has a StartDate that is greater than the StartDate for the incomplete row (Essentially, incomplete rows should be connected to a genuine if present and once a genuine row is found it should close that grouping and treat future rows as separate events). Then I must be able to set a process Start date for each row which is equal to the lowest Start date within that group of processID and mark the last row (the one with the greatest StartDate) with a ProcessCount in a separate column.

Apologies for my lack of descriptive ability here, hopefully the code (written in Python 3.6) I have so far will better explain my desired outcome. The code works but as you can see relies on nested loops which I don't like. I have tried researching around to find out how to vectorise this but I am struggling to get my head around the concept for this problem.

Any help you can provide me with in straightening out the loops in this code would be most appreciated and really help me better understand how to apply this to other tasks going forwards.

**Data**

```
df_dict = {'ClientNumber': {0: 1234, 1: 1234, 2: 1234, 3: 123, 4: 123, 5: 123, 6: 12, 7: 12, 8: 1}, 'Genuine_Incomplete': {0: 'Incomplete', 1: 'Genuine', 2: 'Genuine', 3: 'Incomplete', 4: 'Incomplete', 5: 'Genuine', 6: 'Incomplete', 7: 'Incomplete', 8: 'Genuine'}, 'StartDate': {0: Timestamp('2018-01-01 00:00:00'), 1: Timestamp('2018-01-05 00:00:00'), 2: Timestamp('2018-03-01 00:00:00'), 3: Timestamp('2018-01-01 00:00:00'), 4: Timestamp('2018-01-03 00:00:00'), 5: Timestamp('2018-01-10 00:00:00'), 6: Timestamp('2018-01-01 00:00:00'), 7: Timestamp('2018-06-02 00:00:00'), 8: Timestamp('2018-01-01 00:00:00')}}



df = pd.DataFrame(data=df_dict)

df["ID"] = df.index
df["Process_Start_Date"] = np.nan
df["ProcessCode"] = np.nan
df["ProcessCount"] = np.nan


grouped_df = df.groupby('ClientNumber')
for key, item in grouped_df:
    newdf = grouped_df.get_group(key)
    newdf.sort_values(by=["StartDate"], inplace=True)
    c = 1
    for i in newdf.iterrows():
        i = i[0]
        GI = df.loc[i, "Genuine_Incomplete"]
        proc_code = "{}_{}".format(df.loc[i, "ClientNumber"],c)
        df.loc[i, "ProcessCode"] = proc_code
        if GI == "Genuine":
            c += 1

grouped_df = df.groupby('ProcessCode')
for key, item in grouped_df:
    newdf = grouped_df.get_group(key)
    newdf.sort_values(by=["StartDate"], inplace=True)
    df.loc[newdf.ID.iat[-1], "ProcessCount"] = 1
    for i in newdf.iterrows():
        i = i[0]
        df.loc[i, "Process_Start_Date"] = df.loc[newdf.ID.iat[0], "StartDate"]
```

- Note - You may have noticed my use of the df["ID"] which is just a copy of the index. I know this is not good practice but I couldn't work out how to set values from other columns using the index. Any suggestions for doing this are also very welcome.